Android app very slow loading with multiple fragments in view pager
[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am getting crazy. My app has view pager , with  6 fragments. Each fragments has sub-fragments into another viewapager ( ~ 4 fragments for each main fragment). So , total fragments is about 6x4 = 24 fragments.
I have set viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(max fragment count); to all view pager to make scrolling fast, not laggy
Issue : Very slow app loading , that is variable from device to device , eg :
Lenovo K10 note (L38111)  Phone            Phone   -  6GB RAM  -2x2.2 GHz          : Loads in 5 seconds
Samsung Galaxy A02s(SM-A025F/DS.)  Phone   -  3GB RAM  -1.8GHz               : Loads in 90 seconds
Samsung Galaxy A14                                Phone   -  4GB RAM                               : Loads in 45 seconds
Samsung Galaxy TAB A  -                        Tablet   -  2GB RAM  -2.0 GHz              : Loads in 7 seconds
Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite -                       Tablet   -  4GB RAM                                : Loads in 21 seconds
How to accelerate app startup time to be < 10 seconds. And why is this variations in loading time, though it is slow in some android systems with higher specs.
Update : memory stays at 64BM for around 70 seconds, then increase to 140MB in just 3 seconds before app loads
UPDATE -------------------------------------------
I have  updated the code to use AsyncLayoutInflater, which has dramatically speed up app startup . below is my code used into each fragment :
View final_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view, container, false);
 ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)final_view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

AsyncLayoutInflater asyncInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getActivity());
asyncInflater.inflate(R.layout.customersms_frg, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInflateFinished(View v, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(Customer_SMS.this, v);
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       if (final_view instanceof ViewGroup) {
           ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) final_view;
            viewGroup.addView(v);
        }
    }
});

return final_view;

Issue :
app starts in 6 seconds , which is great for me. However, seems that main UI is blocked. ie , when user  scroll pager to move to 2nd fragment,  >> app not responsive for ~ 20 seconds, then scroll occurrs.  I have attached my app trace into
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Iw1NsF_GBGbKa8dsgzFsZl9xWIHpB9O/view?usp=sharing

I (and I assume others) don't have the time or inclination to analyze your trace for you with zero context of what your code is doing. Again, profile your code, analyze the trace for yourself, identify the bottlenecks, optimize or offload to a background thread, rinse and repeat. Good luck.


How to accelerate app startup time to be < 10 seconds.


Profile your app.
Identify the bottleneck(s).
Optimize.
Go back to 1 until you're satisfied.

If the slowless is due to inflating layouts, look at AsyncLayoutInflater.

And why is this variations in loading time, though it is slow in some android systems with higher specs.

"Higher system specs" is one (or several) of lots of variables. Do all of these devices have the exact same OS version? Disk space? Apps installed? Apps running in the background? Battery level? Etc, etc?

I totally agree with you . I have run Profile app. but i see memory,CPU & Engery chart. where to check which function taking much time ? specially Into. logcat, i see app freezes for abotu 40 sec before Mainactivity is displayed

App speed is determine primarily by the CPU - so start there. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler

CPU profile chart seems very stable. I noticed that Memory stays at 60MB for around 50 seconds , then increases to 140MB just 2 seconds before app mainactivity is displayed

OK, so profile your memory as well. Loading up 24(!) fragments into memory will eat up quite a bit of RAM and allocating that memory will take some time, so your memory increase and CPU usage is not surprising.

With that said, do you really need 24 fragments loaded and ready all the time just to keep things "not laggy"? How many of those 24 fragments is an average user actually going to interact with in a given session?

you are right. I have removed some fragments, and app loads faster. But , are there a way to load fragments in thread. I just need to have good user experience, not to wait for 30 seconds for fragment to load. NB. I have added screenshot for Profiler

needs only 5 fragments on average, but , if he wants to use other, it will load in 30 sec, which is very long time. I think about lazy loading fragments in background. would this be good practice ?

Fragments, as UI elements, must be created and loaded on the Main thread. 30 seconds to load one fragment is absurd. You need to identify what is taking so long and move that to a background thread / coroutine. If the slowless is due to inflating layouts, look at AsyncLayoutInflater

checked AsyncLayoutInflater, looks promising to speed up app load, but fragment is empty. OnCreateview code is : AsyncLayoutInflater asyncInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getActivity());
asyncInflater.inflate(R.layout.showmenu, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
@Override
public void onInflateFinished(View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(ShowMenu.this, view);
initSmartTab(view);
InitializeTitleBar(view);
}

});
return null;

seems that such delay is mostly due to layout inflation, though not that complex. I eg, have part of the xml containing Linearlayout , with 8 textvies, >> this reduced overall load time by 3 seconds. crazy !!

I had successfully implemented AsyncLayoutInflater ,app loads in 6 seconds. the initial is loaded sucessfully. ,but app freezes  for ~15 seconds . ie , when click any button in first fragment, nothing happens till 15 sec passes. my general code for Fragment inflations is below. I do not think it is related to inflation , which runs sucessfully, but related to Main thread other tasks. but cannot find.
return final_view;

my code is :
View final_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view, container, false);
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)final_view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
AsyncLayoutInflater asyncInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getActivity());
asyncInflater.inflate(R.layout.customersms_frg, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {

@Override
public void onInflateFinished(View v, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(Customer_SMS.this, v);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if (final_view instanceof ViewGroup) {
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) final_view;
viewGroup.addView(v);
}
}
});
return final_view;

shall i share trace file?

Please update your original question with additional information like code snippets. Your code samples in the comments are basically illegible.

question updated with sample code for AsyncLayoutinflator , also app trace record link attached.

dominicoder : can you set your comment for asynclayoutinflator , to enable me to set as answer

I updated my answer with that comment.
